# Update UI element from thread by arguments

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use this code for updating a label from a separate thread but it's not working. Can someone help me with how to modify this function so that I can call it from within a separate thread?

```
Public Class Threader
  Private Sub message_UI_Update(email As String, message1 As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf message_UI_Update), email, message1)
    Else
      Label5.Text = email
      Label6.Text = message1
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

**--Update--**

After some research I was able to achieve this with this code. I hope I am using the correct approach.

```
Public Class Threader
  Public Delegate Sub mydelegate(str As String, message1 As String)

  Private Sub message_UI_Update(email As String, message1 As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New mydelegate(AddressOf message_UI_Update), email, message1)
    Else
      Label5.Text = email
      Label6.Text = message1
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have used the same approach that you provided in your edited answer before, and it works. I have run into some deadlock issues with it though (which i was able to fix by using BeginInvoke instead) However i must say that if i had to to it again i wouldnt use this approach. Instead i would make any UI calls from the UI thread itself, and if i need to do any work on a separate thread between these calls, use Async Await and Task.Run() syntax to do so. That's just my 2 cents though, maybe someone with more experience has a better idea

Answer (score -1):

You can use Invoke (if you need it instantly) or BeginInvoke (on next paint event) like this.

```
Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                 Label5.Text = email
                 Label6.Text = message1
               End Sub)
```

And you can put it in the thread/Sub where you do your work with labels, you don't need an additional sub for it.

Comment: That's how I used it, probably not the best way. More experienced people could comment on that, I'm not even a beginner and this simply works without issues so that's why I suggested it.

Comment: @Devcon Why? He can put the code in the same method where email and message1 are, there is no need to send them to another method that's invoked. Like button click start bgw, bgw gets email data and does me.invoke(label.text=email) instead of regular label.text=email for ui thread.

Comment: i don't know :P i wrote same answer as you but i deleted it when i saw he wanted to add those with invoke :)